# How to represent multi-dimensional array in pointer format?

Tags: c++, arrays

For one dimensional array, I have no problem accessing array element. For example --

```
#include<typeinfo>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::string;
int main()
{
        int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
        cout << *(a + 0);
        return 0;
}
```

But when I am trying for 2 dimensional array, I am getting output of the kind --

```
#include<typeinfo>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::string;
int main()
{
        int a[][3] = {1, 2, 3};
        cout << *(a + 2);
        return 0;
}
```

Output --

```
0x7ffca0f7ebcc
```

How can I get output as 2(I will get 2 either by row major or column major order, but c++ follows row major array representation) in the format described in 1st example?

Comment: That's because `*(a + 2)` for the second case yields a `int(*)[3]` result, so you get a pointer printed. Now how would you get the object from the pointer? (Also what's up with the irrelevant includes and usings...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the third element of the first row.

```
#include <iostream>    
int main()
{
    int a[][3] = {1, 2, 3};
    std::cout << *(*a + 2);
}
```

Although you might find `a[0][2]` easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

For raw arrays, C++ inherits the rule from C that

```
a[i]
```

is transformed to

```
*(a + i);
```

To access a two-dimensional array, we can apply this rule twice:

```
a[i][j] => *(a[i] + j) => *(*(a + i) + j)
```

Although obviously the `a[i][j]` syntax is a lot easier to understand.